# Why does Google search not show some of our blog results with a date next to them, while some do

Tags: html

I have tried it with `meta` tags. I do not understand, how google picks the date for search result? And as in this case, if Google takes it from the `meta` tags. Why are some of the results not displaying the date, while some others do?

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-11-05T00:00:56+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-02-28T10:41:21+00:00" />
```

Comment: Could you share your meta tags?

Comment: <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-11-05T00:00:56+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-02-28T10:41:21+00:00" />

Comment: these are the meta tags i used for date.